# How to cache data in phone using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm currently writing a mobile application with Cordova. My mobile application concept is like this :

1. User opens the Application
2. If the User's phone has an active internet connection, the application will request data from a webserver via JSON and **store that data locally on the phone** (replacing data that was previously stored). If the User's phone doesn't have an active internet... then the application will show the data that was saved earlier (when an active connection to the server was present).

This is my first time writing a mobile application, I was not sure what this process was called, so i referred to it as  **`cache`**. Will i need to use a plugin? If yes, what plugin would i need to install into my application? and how to code it correctly? Currently, i'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement offline storage capability in your app using various API provided by the browser without having to install any plugins. (I would start looking at `localStorage`)

Here's the link to the documentation:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html